# Library linking in linux

Tags: c++, linux, libraries

I am new in this domain.
I am installing a library that links to another library (gsl) at run time as follows:

```
g++ x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp -o abc -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas
```

I am currently working on a server and hence do not have root privileges.

gsl is a dependency and therefore I did a local installation of gsl. Following are the steps I followed:

```
1) Downloaded the gsl-latest.tar.gz
2) tar -zxvf gsl-latest.tar.gz
3) From inside the gsl-1.16 (latest) folder I did:
   a) ./configure --prefix=local-folder-path
   b) make
   c) make check
   d) make install
   Everything is successfully completed.
```

Now, since the main library links it as run time, I set the path to this bin in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/a/b/c/gsl-1.16-bin/bin/
```

Now, when I go to the main library's folder and do a 'make' it still gives me the following errors such as:

```
error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory
error: ‘gsl_vector_get’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘gsl_vector_set’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘gsl_vector_get’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘gsl_vector_set’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘gsl_vector_memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
At global scope:
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘gsl_vector’ with no type
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
```

Do I need to set the path somewhere else too?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Your "main library" compilation is looking for a header file "gsl/gsl_vector.h" that can not be found. when you compile you must specify the include path "-I /path/to/include/directory" where this directory contains the "gsl" directory

Comment: I did g++ x.cpp y.cpp z.cpp -o abc -lm -I  /a/b/c/gsl-1.16/. Is that correct?

but i still get the following errors:
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_taus'
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_alloc'
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_set'
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_uniform'
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_uniform'
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_free'

Comment: have you tried "pkg-config --cflags gsl"  - if the gsl library is pkg-config friendly this should display the include path - you can then use backticks to inject this into the compile command (i.e. `pkg-config --cflags gsl`

Comment: The errors you'rre getting are linker errors - which would suggest to me it is now finding the header file

Comment: Yes the pkg-config --cflags gsl worked. How can the linker errors be solved?

Comment: by adding "pkg-config --libs gsl" in backticks to the compile command, possibly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `include` paths. You need to add `-I` to compile line to find the directory.

Also maybe specify RPATH [Wikipedia RPATH](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjz-Lqy1uXHAhWBvRQKHb_JAuQ&usg=AFQjCNEHP7FrRf6ZxwN2GoQEEmQmbp2FEQ&sig2=kGPYUtIaGsVNVXZklXj14w) to specify where to find libraries